# How can I write a shell script to filter the last command?

Tags: shell, grep, scripting, last

I want to write a script for login statistics. I want to count how many times a user logged in, and then display them in ascending, or descending order, given by the end user. The problme being, i don't know how to write a script that could count how many times a user logged in. I have to use the last command.

Comment: Can't you do `last $username` for every user, and count the lines being returned? You will have to truncate the last 2 ones though. Also, be warned that the `wtmp` file only holds records for a specific timeframe.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

echo '1 - ascending, 0 - descending, please choose:'
read x
echo 'how many lines do you need?:'
read y

if [ $x -eq 1 ]; then
        echo `last ` >> last.txt
fi

after I have the last.txt file, i need to count how many times one user logged in, then put the data in ascending/descending order. At the end, I have to display A certain amount of lines, strating from 1. Can't really figure out how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
userlist=$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1)
for user in $userlist; do
        timesloggedin=$(last $user | head -n -2 | wc -l);
        echo $timesloggedin $user;
done | sort -r
```

This gets the name of ALL the users on the system, including daemon accounts etc.
If you don't want that, supply `userlist` with a list of your usernames.
To get the output in ascending order, drop the `-r` flag to sort.